# What caused visions seen by Saki?

Tags: from-the-new-world

During the series, Saki often sees really weird visions, sometimes very phantasmagorical. If I remember correctly, first time was when she was trapped with Satoru after encountering hostile bakenezumi.

So, to put it short - what was actually source of her visions? It's clearly not normal for human to see things out of nowhere. I may understand why she is seeing visions after

> Shun becomes Karma-demon (may be impact of his power on her brain/subconsciousness or something),

but not for first time at least.

Comment: i don't recall a scene when Saki and Satoru were trapped except for when Saki was remembering what the False Minoshiro was talking about in regards to using sensual touching as a means to relieve stress but i think some of the weird almost eldritch scenes might have been Shun's doing given he's in [one of them](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/26688/1587)